# How best to add Author or Artist to product

Tags: taxonomy

What is the best way to set up Authors or Artists to a Product (on a book store) where I can also have pages created for each Author? 
Author pages would include an image and a description including Products listed on the site from that Author.
Currently I am building the site with a WooCommerce template Kalium & there must be a better way to handle authors than using Attributes & hand entering pages for each Author.
Sorry, I am a newb here...
Thanks for your help.

Comment: When creating the author/artist attributes select "Enable archives" and each one will automatically get a page listing their products.

Comment: Thank you Jacob!
I have now also installed  https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/  so as to have Author's images but am not fluent enough to know what code goes on the Authors' page to display the image.
...baby steps..